# Is it a good idea to use rowguid as unique key in database design?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key, data-modeling

SQL Server provides the type [rowguid]. I like to use this as unique primary key, to identify a row for update. The benefit shows up if you dump the table and reload it, no mess with SerialNo (identity) columns.

In the special case of distributed databases like offline copies on notebooks or something like that, nothing else works.

What do you think? Too much overhead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a **primary key** in the logical sense (uniquely identifying your rows) - yes, absolutely, makes total sense.

**BUT:** in SQL Server, the primary key is by default also the **clustering key** on your table, and using a `ROWGUID` as the clustering key is a really really bad idea. See Kimberly Tripp's excellent [GUIDs as a PRIMARY and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) article for in-depth reasons why not to use GUIDs for clustering.

Since the GUID is by definition random, you'll have a horrible index fragmentation and thus really really bad performance on insert, update, delete and select statements.

Also, since the clustering key is being added to each and every field of each and every non-clustered index on your table, you're wasting a lot of space - both on disk as well as in server RAM - when using 16-byte GUID vs. 4-byte INT.

So: yes, as a primary key, a ROWGUID has its merits - but if you do use it, definitely avoid using that column as your clustering key in the table! Use a INT IDENTITY() or something similar for that.

For a clustering key, ideally you should look for four features:

- stable (never changing)
- unique
- as small as possible
- ever-increasing

INT IDENTITY() ideally suits that need. And yes - the clustering key must be unique since it's used to physically locate a row in the table - if you pick a column that can't be guaranteed to be unique, SQL Server will actually add a four-byte uniqueifier to your clustering key - again, not something you want to have....

Check out [The Clustered Index Debate Continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) - another wonderful and insightful article by Kim Tripp (the "Queen of SQL Server Indexing") in which she explains all these requirements very nicely and thoroughly.

MArc

Comment: The size of the GUID should not be an issue here. In direct answer to the question there is nothing extra offered here except a "don't forget to choose another clustered index" warning. Because the ROWGUID is also the row ID internally, there should be no wasted space as the target of the index (the ID of the row) will be written in there anyway. Or is there a limitation/lack of optimization meaning MS must write the GUID twice in the index even when it is the ROWGUID? I'd doubt it, but please clarify if you know otherwise.

Comment: @CodeChief: the size of the *clustering key* is **very much** an issue in SQL Server! It really should be as small as possible, since it's also included in **all** nonclustered indexes on the same table. 4 byte vs. 16 byte makes a **huge** difference if you have 100 million rows and 15 nonclustered indexes!

Comment: in case it wasn't clear I REALLY am suggesting this has nothing to do with clustered indexes! If you must then DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() as documented in MSDN and already answered by others here. Anyway talking about large databases, if they're for large customers and important then you should plan for scalability or have highly-availably as a requirement, which leads back to ROWGUID anyway.

Comment: It does so, because the primary key by default is also the clustering key in SQL Server ... and a great majority of DB devs won't even really care about the difference between primary key and clustering key .... so it does matter...

Comment: So we get back to my first point, it's just a warning not something wrong with ROWGUID itself. Also from MSDN they tell you that there is no inherent relation between the ROWGUID column option and being a primary key, you have to actually set that on the column explicitly. Just re-tested with SSMS 2012 and sure it's not set to primary key by default using the GUI (when setting ROWGUID option to yes in properties window) and neither T-SQL. Only way you get a primary key is by setting that separate GUI option or adding PRIMARY KEY constraint explicitly in TSQL.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but there is another solution -- you can use a COMB technique to ensure that your GUID keys are sequentially increasing. (See https://github.com/richardtallent/RT.Comb for my implementation of this, for example.) While the "as small as possible" rule is still a good rule of thumb, the difference between a GUID and a 32- or 64-bit int just doesn't matter as much as it did nearly 10 years ago. YMMV, but I've been using COMBs for well over a decade with no noticeable performance difference vs. my int-PK tables.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with rowguid is that if you use it for your clustered index you end up constantly re-calculating your table pages for record inserts.  A sequential guid ( NEWSEQUENTIALID() ) often works better.

Comment: Interesting but doesn't work completely because according to the MSDN documentation the sequential GUID is only sequential from when the computer last started and will create lower values in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Our offline application is used in branch offices and we have a central database in our main office. To synchronize the database into central database we have used rowguid column in all tables. May be there are better solutions but it is easier for us. We have not faced any major problem till date in last 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the accepted answer, the uniqueidentifier datatype in SQL Server is indeed a good candidate for a primary clustering key; so long as you keep it sequential.

This is easily accomplished using (newsequentialid()) as the default value for the column.

If you actually read [Kimberly Tripp's article](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) you will find that sequentially generated GUIDs are actually a good candidate for primary clustering keys in terms of fragmentation and the only downside is size.

If you have large rows with few indexes, the extra few bytes in a GUID may be negligible. Sure the issue compounds if you have short rows with numerous indexes, but this is something you have to weigh up depending on your own situation.

Using sequential uniqueidentifiers makes a lot of sense when you're going to use merge replication, especially when dealing with identity seeding and the woes that ensue.

Server calss storage isn't cheap, but I'd rather have a database that uses a bit more space than one that screeches to a halt when your automatically assigned identity ranges overlap.